# Union Pay Integration

Tags: payment-gateway

I have setup Union Pay SDK according to the instructions as given in 
https://developer.unionpayintl.com/cjweb/api/detail?apiSvcId=5

I am getting response code 11(Signature verification failed) for Test Credentials

Please find my request and response messages.Please help me if I am passing incorrect parameters.

I am using...

merchant Id-709034470110013
AccNo-6250946000000016
Request URL:https://gateway.test.95516.com/gateway/api/backTransReq.do

Complete Request message:

```
accNo=Hr5Nncue0olERbHVJJY+p2sYR1FwzSFr5QOThg4vDdGCxZTyQvv0yzne3Lc/rD0ILzlQ+rEfSJN/sKjXvFg7dPtMfk4jFzMrPvlmA3F5ituDD4Y3aswwJvJ7wXLAB8Hq1wgvvXxeZ8YA00QBypWizkq1Qhl3Lec/8Ho+kdvdQS5JeK4Iz468UoBHWc6EPjPB713ovwOGd+cdYiRdpDxv+9LR6sdzfFZD6oAyqdSwcpoqvav7vB8xo1tqnhDlAy/GaYwg4909b3JQvfjyd7faxQhAouVnOcwIGaDOsghuDOrginsVj7H7OoosQ3uwKQpsImMSnx80wWw878MKFAzN+w==
accessType=0
backUrl=http://222.222.222.222:8080/ACPSample_WuTiaoZhuan_Token/backRcvResponse
bizType=000301
certId=68759663125
channelType=07
currencyCode=156
customerInfo=e3Ntc0NvZGU9MTExMTExfQ==
encoding=UTF-8
encryptCertId=68759622183
merId=709034470110013
orderId=20181203165515
signMethod=01
signature=gDJR9vD0g1oQQuz/28Ofc2lFRj/sVBcjdNZr4BQmLuYItwxm4GQwuphT17+z00/Uo/g4W+p+h5ksIueTFcRUncVqWvsjFQ5hgQGwnJCBcCWHWeilR1cZ3Zxm8UL8zmN+G96cLQ1UsQ5ifWUgFSNQTRKCOSQsYR/4/nnipk4+ISMPvN2fSRVpQ/16b+/JtTw2jTs0w65Tc769SOIfuXKUB9JjiSVtS/5jd/4tuzgasZOwXVPxpA8pZbwJsoxQa90W6Vvp1ez+iMnYsvINz2RrDmurR1wZNXf1FoYVCdszBZA+dA1fSeAkmvbrN0x8NzCP702XaXmN7m8aKwddK+AAOA==
txnAmt=1000
txnSubType=01
txnTime=20181203165515
txnType=01
version=5.1.0
```

Response message:

```
accNo=Hr5Nncue0olERbHVJJY+p2sYR1FwzSFr5QOThg4vDdGCxZTyQvv0yzne3Lc/rD0ILzlQ+rEfSJN/sKjXvFg7dPtMfk4jFzMrPvlmA3F5ituDD4Y3aswwJvJ7wXLAB8Hq1wgvvXxeZ8YA00QBypWizkq1Qhl3Lec/8Ho+kdvdQS5JeK4Iz468UoBHWc6EPjPB713ovwOGd+cdYiRdpDxv+9LR6sdzfFZD6oAyqdSwcpoqvav7vB8xo1tqnhDlAy/GaYwg4909b3JQvfjyd7faxQhAouVnOcwIGaDOsghuDOrginsVj7H7OoosQ3uwKQpsImMSnx80wWw878MKFAzN+w==
accessType=0
backUrl=http://222.222.222.222:8080/ACPSample_WuTiaoZhuan_Token/backRcvResponse
bizType=000301
certId=68759663125
channelType=07
currencyCode=156
customerInfo=e3Ntc0NvZGU9MTExMTExfQ==
encoding=UTF-8
encryptCertId=68759622183
merId=709034470110013
orderId=20181203165515
respCode=11
respMsg=[9100004]Signature verification failed
signMethod=01
signPubKeyCert=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIFEBJJZVgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwWDELMAkGA1UEBhMC Q04xMDAuBgNVBAoTJ0NoaW5hIEZpbmFuY2lhbCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhv cml0eTEXMBUGA1UEAxMOQ0ZDQSBURVNUIE9DQTEwHhcNMTcxMTAxMDcyNDA4WhcN MjAxMTAxMDcyNDA4WjB3MQswCQYDVQQGEwJjbjESMBAGA1UEChMJQ0ZDQSBPQ0Ex MQ4wDAYDVQQLEwVDVVBSQTEUMBIGA1UECxMLRW50ZXJwcmlzZXMxLjAsBgNVBAMU JTA0MUBaMjAxNy0xMS0xQDAwMDQwMDAwOlNJR05AMDAwMDAwMDEwggEiMA0GCSqG SIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDDIWO6AESrg+34HgbU9mSpgef0sl6avr1d bD/IjjZYM63SoQi3CZHZUyoyzBKodRzowJrwXmd+hCmdcIfavdvfwi6x+ptJNp9d EtpfEAnJk+4quriQFj1dNiv6uP8ARgn07UMhgdYB7D8aA1j77Yk1ROx7+LFeo7rZ Ddde2U1opPxjIqOPqiPno78JMXpFn7LiGPXu75bwY2rYIGEEImnypgiYuW1vo9UO G47NMWTnsIdy68FquPSw5FKp5foL825GNX3oJSZui8d2UDkMLBasf06Jz0JKz5AV blaI+s24/iCfo8r+6WaCs8e6BDkaijJkR/bvRCQeQpbX3V8WoTLVAgMBAAGjgfQw gfEwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUz3CdYeudfC6498sCQPcJnf4zdIAwSAYDVR0gBEEwPzA9 BghggRyG7yoBATAxMC8GCCsGAQUFBwIBFiNodHRwOi8vd3d3LmNmY2EuY29tLmNu L3VzL3VzLTE0Lmh0bTA5BgNVHR8EMjAwMC6gLKAqhihodHRwOi8vdWNybC5jZmNh LmNvbS5jbi9SU0EvY3JsMjQ4NzIuY3JsMAsGA1UdDwQEAwID6DAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU mQQLyuqYjES7qKO+zOkzEbvdFwgwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUF BwMEMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQAujhBuOcuxA+VzoUH84uoFt5aaBM3vGlpW KVMz6BUsLbIpp1ho5h+LaMnxMs6jdXXDh/du8X5SKMaIddiLw7ujZy1LibKy2jYi YYfs3tbZ0ffCKQtv78vCgC+IxUUurALY4w58fRLLdu8u8p9jyRFHsQEwSq+W5+bP MTh2w7cDd9h+6KoCN6AMI1Ly7MxRIhCbNBL9bzaxF9B5GK86ARY7ixkuDCEl4XCF JGxeoye9R46NqZ6AA/k97mJun//gmUjStmb9PUXA59fR5suAB5o/5lBySZ8UXkrI pp/iLT8vIl1hNgLh0Ghs7DBSx99I+S3VuUzjHNxL6fGRhlix7Rb8 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
signature=Rb1I3QsA3pzX7WW10uh6x2GVZ28Wgnjhc0sE+nbIMcZdugtB3tBMGj+1MuOCkMvo4q+UTCYtH1f7GtgQupYVMKdU0ewdEtMjGixk1kfffw+lvcXSEKp6Ktlcam2bABMQNF9ovsMbwWy5Ez18wc44R0qVwkf+NjYh5M5XLb1TnI8ZOtSCNha5Wr90UpopcYsKNEUjz7ppKEJwXehVsd5d9pzZZI8iP4f6n7CnjjtHzTnRyfxRXMppdwZfXPuhNTXRYhG8p3/qjgW48fOvOo7dq61sO13a3YUmompNMmMb+VEWuOLj7NhpouL+ZvyA39JNl1cawN47Qor9bxg/22/wrQ==
txnAmt=1000
txnSubType=01
txnTime=20181203165515
txnType=01
version=5.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API using is the 无跳转-token版(后台开通), according to the docs.
The txnType should be 79.